# Using parallel inductors on LM2596

Tags: inductor, buck, step-down

In the datasheet of LM2596, 33uH or 47uH inductors are recommended for 5V output. I can't find any high amperage inductors of those values. So that if I use 100uH of 2 inductors in paralell(they will act as 50uH together), will the circuit work in real life like in the theory?

datasheet of LM2596:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf

Comment: If the inductors are identical that *should* work. However, I find it odd that you cannot find any high-current inductors, I can easily find them: https://www.ebay.com/itm/5Pcs-Wound-Toroid-Core-Inductor-For-33Uh-3A-Mah-Lm2596-Wire-Wind-Ic-New-X/232323080855?epid=875057066&hash=item361788e297:g:BJoAAOSw5cNYHiGQ or SMD version: https://www.ebay.com/itm/5PCS-104R-33UH-330-power-inductors-10X10X4-high-power-SMD-inductors/251166984063?hash=item3a7ab8077f:g:0soAAOSwyQtV1-A~

Comment: Yes, right. But paypal does not work here for now :)

Comment: The same parts can also be ordered from Farnell, Mouser, Digikey but you will pay more in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and find the correctly specified single inductor is my advice because although two identical parallel 100 uH inductors will produce 50 uH theoretically, lower self-resonant-frequency from higher inductor parts and magnetic-cross-coupling of the two inductors is enough to raise concerns.

You also need to be aware that larger values of inductance on the same size core require more turns and will saturate at a lower current - this shouldn't be a problem with two in parallel because they will share the total current - I'm adding this in case you thought you might be able to use smaller parts.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Table of possible inductors (plus part numbers) in the datasheet you posted. Table 1 on page 19.

Comment: I'm trying to obtain these values with connecting higher value inductors in parallel.

Comment: yes but only because you cant find single inductors which fit your needs when i understood correctly? Keep in mind that two inductors will most likely result in more volume and/or PCB area. Quick search on digikey resulted in 47µ inductors up to 14A rated current.